# Preserving PowerShell function return type

Tags: powershell, casting

In my PowerShell script I need to call a .NET method with the following signature:

```cs
class CustomList : System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { }

interface IProcessor { void Process(CustomList list); }
```

I made a helper function to generate the list:

```
function ConvertTo-CustomList($obj)
{
    $list = New-Object CustomList
    if ($obj.foo) {$list.Add($obj.foo)}
    if ($obj.bar) {$list.Add($obj.bar)}
    return $list
}
```

Then I call the method:

```
$list = ConvertTo-CustomList(@{'foo'='1';'bar'='2'})
$processor.Process($list)
```

However, the call fails with the following error:

```
Cannot convert argument "list", with value: "System.Object[]", for "Process" to type "CustomList"
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

So PowerShell by some reason converts a `CustomList` with two items to an `object[]` with two items and cannot convert it back at method call. If I call `ConvertTo-CustomList(@{'foo'='1'})`, just a `string` is returned.

I tried to put a cast here and there, but this does not help, the execution fails at the point of cast after function return.

So how can force the `ConvertTo-CustomList` function to return the original `CustomList`? I would not like to initialize the `CustomList` in-place because in real code the initialization is more complex than in this example.

A possible workaround is to implement the helper function in C# using the `Add-Type` commandlet, but I would prefer to keep my code in single language.

Comment: How did you add a reference to your library so that `New-Object CustomList` actually uses your special object?

Comment: Also note, everything in powershell is `object` unless otherwise cast. `'foo'='1'` probably needs to be `'foo' = [string]"1"` to force it to be the string that `CustomList` expects.

Comment: NB. you aren't calling your function correctly. PowerShell functions don't have `()` when called. `ConvertTo-CustomList @{'foo'='1';'bar'='2'}`. Using `()` will bite you when you have several parameters, as everything in the parens will become an array in the first parameter variable, and the other parameter variables will be $null.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
return $list
```

causes the collection to unravel and get "piped" out one by one. Such is the nature of PowerShell.

You can prevent this, by wrapping the output variable itself in a 1-item array, using the unary array operator `,`:

```
return ,$list
```

Comment: It's better to just omit the `return` altogether and put `$list` on a line on its own. Your method is forcing it to be an array that contains an object that is `$list`

Comment: "an array that contains an object that is `$list`" Which is then automatically unpacked on assignment

Comment: That doesn't seem to help; this in PS 4, and using an ArrayList because I don't have OP's CustomList - http://pastie.org/private/tzjcqn08m5zfrixkjswneq - it's an ArrayList inside the function and still an object[] after returning

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: The only reason your ArrayList example returns object[] is that ArrayList's Add() method returns a value (the old element count), which pollutes the function's output stream and thus returns a regular PS array (object[]), whose _last_ element is the ArrayList. If you use a generic type (e.g., `System.Collections.Generic.List[string]`), you'll see that Mathias's claim is correct (alternatively, use `$null = $list.Add(...)`).