# Can't prevent PowerShell from changing the return object's type

Tags: xml, powershell, return

When I am returning XML object from a function, PowerShell is changing its type to `Object[]`:

[image]

I read here:
[PowerShell changes return object's type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498320/powershell-changes-return-objects-type)
[Preserving PowerShell function return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257354/preserving-powershell-function-return-type)
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27035513/How-to-stop-PowerShell-function-changing-return-type-of-ArrayList-or-string.html

How to prevent it and all of them wrote that adding comma `,` in the return should solve it.

I tried:

```
return ,$computer
```

The problem still exist.
It still returns me `Object[]` type instead of `XmlElement` type.

Example code:

```
Function getComputerXML($doc){
    $computer  = $doc.CreateNode("element","Computer",$null)

    $computerSettings = $doc.CreateNode("element","ComputerSettings",$null)
    $computerSettings.SetAttribute("Name","HP") | Out-Null
    $computerSettings.InnerText = "someText"
    $computer.AppendChild($computerSettings)

    return $computer
}

Function main(){

   [xml]$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument

   $computer = getComputerXML $doc
   #$computers.AppendChild($computer)
}

main
```

Comment: `[void]$computer.AppendChild($computerSettings)`

Comment: @PetSerAl, it works. Can you explain more why this fix work?

Comment: @E235 Because `AppendChild()` emits the newly added child node. Btw the code you've posted is (unlike the screenshot) incomplete

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I only removed the three rows after the `[xml]$doc=....` for simplicity. It doesn't affect the problem.

Comment: It makes the `main()` function throw an error (since `$computers` doesnt exist), might as well remove it completely

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen commented it. Btw, I found this problem only when I did the AppendChild in the main and received an error because it tried to add `Object[]` type instead of `XmlElement`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function output [consists of everything that isn't captured](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/effective-powershell-item-7-understanding-output/) and is always a .NET object.

```
Function main(){

   [xml]$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument

   $computer = getComputerXML $doc
   [void]$computers.AppendChild($computer)
}
```

You can check the difference of with/out `[void]` like this:

```
$computers| foreach {$_.GetType().Fullname}
```

> The return keyword allows you to exit the function at any particular
>   point, ... but we do not *need* to use the return keyword like we do
>   in C style function.    You may also "optionally" specify an argument
>   to the return statement that will cause the argument to be output just
>   before returning.  "return $xy" does *not* mean that the functions
>   only output is the contents of the $xyvariable.   ...
>
> You have to be diligent when you write a PowerShell function to ensure
>   you get only the output you want.  This usually means redirecting
>   unwanted output to $null (or optionally type casting the expression
>   with the unwanted output to [void]).